# How do I group objects returned by a REST API based on a value inside that object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping, jira-rest-api

I'm pretty new to ruby/rails so bear with me.

I'm attempting to take the results returned by the JIRA rest API and render them in a view. I can do that pretty easily using the [jira-ruby](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) gem. The problem I'm having is grouping the results by a specific object inside the object returned by the API (in this case, a "components" field object inside of a "issue" object). I've attempted to use group_by and chunk for this but I'm basically getting the inverse of what I want. Both methods return the same result.

In my controller I have:

```
@issues = @jira_client.Issue.all
```

In my view I have:

```
<% @issues.chunk {|issue_comp| issue_comp.fields["components"]}.each do |comps, issues| %>
    <h2>
        <% comps.each do |comp| %>
            <%= comp["name"] %>
        <% end %>
    </h2>
    <ul>
        <% issues.each do |issue| %>
            <li><p><%= link_to issue.key, "http://localhost:2990/jira/browse/#{issue.key}" %> - <%= issue.summary %></p></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

What I end up with is:

CompA CompB

- IssueA

CompC CompD

- IssueB

CompA CompC CompD

- IssueC

etc.

What I want is:

CompA

- IssueA
- IssueC

CompB

- IssueA

CompC

- IssueB
- IssueC

CompD

- IssueB
- IssueC

The object returned by the API is a pretty convoluted object (i.e. giant array of hashes inside arrays inside of hashes). So, I have to dig pretty deep to get at the component name.

I get the feeling that this shouldn't be as complicated as it seems but I have a terrible habit of making things more complicated than they need to be. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** I created a gist of the full dump that is returned with the above call. Notice the "components" array:

[jira-ruby gem dump for all issues](https://gist.github.com/nosaj3/8edef85fdaee699164d9f1be4db4bf9a)

Comment: We need the sample input and the desired output.

Comment: @Anthony I've added sample input. The desired output is already there unless I'm missing something? Basically, I want to group all issues common to a component by the component name in my view.

Comment: I've looked at your sample data in a JSON viewer and there isn't enough there to demonstrate the problem you're having.  Could you include the data that would generate your desired outcome so we can see it in its raw form?  Be sure to obfuscate your private data, of course.

Comment: @DanLaffan Sorry, you are correct. I created a gist of the full dump. I cleaned it up for private data but there really isn't any as it's all in a dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the data you're getting back from Jira.  This is how it looks to me:

- There is an outer array of Jira Issues.
- Each issue has an "attrs" hash
- Each "attrs" hash contains components.

If this understanding is correct, I think you are attempting to invert that structure so that you can get a complete list of components, then iterate over each of them, and show the Issues that belong to that component.

If that understanding is correct, you have two basic choices:

- Check if you can ask Jira for that information (so you don't have to generate it yourself), or
- Build your own data structure (in memory on in a local DB as you prefer):

Some sample code for building a useful structure in-memory:

```
# in a controller, model, or service class (as you wish)
@components = {}
@jira_issues_array.each do |jira_issue| # from your API call
  jira_issues[:components].each do |jira_component|
    @components[jira_component[:key]] ||= { name: jira_component[:name], issue_keys: [] }
    @components[jira_component[:key]][:issue_keys] << jira_issue[:key]
  end
end
```

In your view, you could iterate over @components like this:

```
# some html.erb file:
<h1>Components and Issues</h1>

<ul>
  <% @components.keys.each do |component_key, component| %>
    <li><%= component[:name] %>
      <ul> <!-- nested -->
        <% component[:issue_keys].each do |issue_key| %>
          <%= @jira_issues_array.find { |issue| issue[:key] == issue_key }[:name] %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Note: Like a typical lazy programmer, I haven't tried this out, but it's really intended to show how you might go about it.  For example, each issue's name is embedded in the attrs section, so you'll need to dig that out a bit.

Finally, if anyone would find this useful, I use [this to analyse and reformat JSON](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu).

HTH - any questions or problems, post a comment.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I plopped this into my environment with only a couple modifications and my view was broken due to undefined method `[]' for #<JIRA::Resource::Issue:0x007fcb2620d9d0>. Which begs the question, should I be storing the responses from the API in my database? I was originally thinking that it wasn't the right thing to do as it seemed an unnecessary step. However, given the complexity of acting on the return data, perhaps it is?

Comment: Your answer provided just enough clues for me to construct a solution. For the record, I'm not currently storing this in my db, so I had to adjust my solution to work with the methods that were available to me through the API in some cases. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of some help! :)  It's always a difficult call to make on whether or not to store API-sourced data locally (on your server' in a database) or go get it every time.  The main challenge is knowing when your DB data is out of date and has been updated remotely.